# Login PowerBI from windows powershell error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-powershell

I am trying to login to POwerBi using below 2 codes and one method is working and other method not

1. This method promopts for selecting credentials stored in windows credential manager and it works

`$cred = Get-Credential`

`echo $cred`

```
UserName                                            Password
--------                                            --------
xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com       System.Security.SecureString
```

`Login-PowerBI -Credential $cred`

```
Environment : Public
TenantId    : xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
ClientId    : xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
Password    : ********
```

2. I want to avoid prompt so I used Get-StoredCredentials

`$cred =$(Get-StoredCredential -Target https://app.xxxx.com/home)`

`echo $cred`
I get same value as before

```
UserName                                            Password
--------                                            --------
xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com       System.Security.SecureString
```

But when I try to login `Login-PowerBI -Credential $cred`
its not working saying AzureADWindowsAuthenticator has stopped working

```
Login-PowerBI : Failed to get ADAL token: Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalClaimChallengeException: AADSTS53000: Device is not in require
d device state: compliant. Conditional Access policy requires a compliant device, and the device is not compliant.
```

Comment: it seems that your machine is not compliant with your corporate Intune Policy.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-compliant-device
You should either become compliant or ask for your user/machine to be exempt.

Comment: But isnt it the same method.. I'm passing same $cred in both cases.. Only the method used to obtained changed

Comment: I think it depends on the policies.  Perhaps there are more relaxed policies for general computing, but stricter ones for Power BI.  I am just speculating though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm absolute beginner in both PowerBi and shell scripting. My requirement is to create a shell script which refreshes a dataflow. Current working script generates a prompt for entering credentials which is what I want to avoid. Is there any other method to access power bi without getting prompt

Comment: @Leo you can use service principal to login powerbi: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount?view=powerbi-ps

Comment: Not sure how to get certificate thumbprint. Only information I have is client id, which I assume to be used as applicaiton id